# Which comments got me the Pundit badge?

Tags: support, comments, badges

I just got a Pundit badge, so I must have 10 comments — somewhere — with 5 votes each.  I'm curious what they are, since I have been leaving more comments lately, except that none of my recent ones has more than one or two votes.  Of course, looking at my comments under the "activity" tab of my page shows only the title and not the votes.  Is there any way to figure this out short of doing a linear search?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/71678/my-most-popular-comments (current data there is from June 27)

Comment: Similar: http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/71222/whats-my-pundit-badge-progress

Comment: These are both good suggestions (though I am not sure what the difference is).  Though since they do used cached data, I still needed to trawl through the 4-point comments to figure out what put me over the edge.

Comment: @RyanReich: They are pretty much the same. There are probably quite a few more equivalent queries to be found on the data explorer (and you can write your own too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, there are SQL queries on data.SX for this, for instance:

- http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/71678/my-most-popular-comments
- http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/71222/whats-my-pundit-badge-progress

The data are cached so the votes appear there delayed. I'm afraid it's not easily possible to get the up-to-date information instantly since caching is necessary to avoid server overloads.